# Schedule script to attach CSV file report to a data source in servicenow

Tags: scheduled-tasks, servicenow

Schedule script to attach CSV file report to a data source in servicenow.
Schedule script that automatically attach csv file to the data source in servicenow.
how can we achieve this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  General guideline: your question will be answered quickly if you share what you have already done (some code) and the exact nature of where you are stuck (error/stack trace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this can be achieved in multiple ways. Bit of a vague description you have there. So I'll just drop a few general ideas for you:

1. If you don't mind turning things around, you could consider an external program push the file directly to ServiceNow and then run the associated TransformMap:
   https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-platform-administration/page/administer/import-sets/task/t_PostCSVOrExcelFilesToImportSet.html
2. If you have an FTP, you can have a scheduled script that will fetch the file from the FTP and run the transform:
   https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-platform-administration/page/administer/import-sets/task/t_ScheduleADataImport.html
3. You could use the MID Server application to have your custom logic of retrieving the file data. This is probably most complex to set up but also giving you the biggest advantages, like having your file encrypted etc. Basically, MID Server checks every couple seconds for a piece of code to be executed (called probes), for example you could trigger some Powershell script sitting on your server with it.

I'm sure there's other options as well. Good luck!